# Sklearn StandardScaler showing incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

I'm using `StandardScaler()` to standardize a pandas dataframe but when I calculate it manually I get different results.

Here is my DataFrame, named `blood_df`:

```
   dbp    sbp  weight  height
0  82.6  132.1      71     172
1  79.1  129.9      79     180
2  81.7  131.2      78     172
3  80.7  132.1      66     166
4  74.9  125.0      70     173
5  79.1  129.1      64     162
6  83.8  133.1      60     164
7  78.4  127.0      67     165
8  82.3  131.6      64     164
9  79.4  129.2      77     179
```

I scale using

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(blood_df)
blood_scaled = scaler.transform(blood_df)
```

to get `blood_scaled`. Using `blood_scaled['dbp'].describe()` I get:

```
count    1.000000e+01
mean     4.618528e-15
std      1.054093e+00
min     -2.163355e+00
25%     -4.489983e-01
50%     -6.122704e-02
75%      7.959515e-01
max      1.469449e+00
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

However, looking at just the column `dbp` of the scaled data, it differs from when I calculate it manually using `z = (x - u) / s`:

```
((blood_df['dbp'] - blood_df['dbp'].mean()) / blood_df['dbp'].std()).describe()
```

gives:

```
count    1.000000e+01
mean     4.418688e-15
std      1.000000e+00
min     -2.052339e+00
25%     -4.259572e-01
50%     -5.808507e-02
75%      7.551059e-01
max      1.394042e+00
Name: dbp, dtype: float64
```

Why are the standard deviations not equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [StandardScaler documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> **Notes**
>
> ...
>
> We use a biased estimator for the standard deviation, equivalent to numpy.std(x, ddof=0). Note that the choice of ddof is
> unlikely to affect model performance.

While from [pandas.DataFrame.std documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html):

> **ddof : int, default 1**
>
> Delta Degrees of Freedom. The divisor used in calculations is N - ddof, where N represents the number of elements.

`ddof` in this case is used in Standard Deviation formula replacing denomintor `N` with `N - ddof`, like:

```
std = (sum((x - x.mean())**2) ** 0.5) / (N - ddof)
```

So, by default, while `StandardScaler` uses `ddof = 0`, `pandas.DataFrame.std` uses `ddof = 1`.

You can see this is the reason for the difference if you try to specify `ddof` in your manual formula:

```
((blood_df['dbp'] - blood_df['dbp'].mean()) / blood_df['dbp'].std(ddof = 0)).describe()
```

Gives the same results as the `StandardScaler`.